# TimeoutError Youtube API A connection attempt failed because the connected party did not properly respond after a period of time

Tags: python, youtube-api, timeout

I'm trying to make a search with youtube API search method. It worked a few days, but since yesterday it started showming me a Timeout Error
The part of the code:

```
def YoutubeSearch():
    # this is used to build our youtube api
    youtube = build('youtube', 'v3', developerKey= 'mykey')
    date_tolook = CalculateDate() #Function to calculate the date to look for 
    request = youtube.search().list(
        type = "channel",
        part = "snippet",
        q = domain_name(ls[15]),
        maxResults = 1
    )
    response = request.execute()
    print(response)
    duration = CalculateVideoDuration()
    if response['pageInfo']['totalResults'] > 0 :
        chanid = response['items'][0]['id']['channelId']
        request2 = youtube.search().list(
            part="snippet",
            type = "video",
            channelId= chanid,
            publishedAfter= date_tolook,
            videoDuration=duration,
            order = "date"
        )
        response2 = request2.execute()
        print(response2)
        if response2['pageInfo']['totalResults'] > 0:
            title = response['items'][0]['snippet']['title']
            videoid = response['items'][0]['id']['videoId']
            request3 = youtube.videos().list(
                part="statistics",
                id = videoid
            )
            response3 = request3.execute()
            print(response)
            numberofviews = response['items'][0]['statistics']['viewCount']
            numberoflikes = response['items'][0]['statistics']['likeCount']
            SendEmail(ls[15], title, numberofviews, numberoflikes)
            CreateCsv(ls[15])
```

The error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\bajan\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\tkinter\__init__.py", line 1921, in __call__
    return self.func(*args)
  File "C:\Users\bajan\Desktop\Informatica\Python\YoutubeSearchBot\lib\site-packages\customtkinter\widgets\ctk_button.py", line 372, in clicked
    self.command()
  File "c:\Users\bajan\Desktop\Informatica\Python\YoutubeSearchBot\main.py", line 70, in doSomething
    YoutubeSearch()
  File "c:\Users\bajan\Desktop\Informatica\Python\YoutubeSearchBot\main.py", line 119, in YoutubeSearch
    response = request.execute()
  File "C:\Users\bajan\Desktop\Informatica\Python\YoutubeSearchBot\lib\site-packages\googleapiclient\_helpers.py", line 130, in positional_wrapper
    return wrapped(*args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\bajan\Desktop\Informatica\Python\YoutubeSearchBot\lib\site-packages\googleapiclient\http.py", line 923, in execute
    resp, content = _retry_request(
  File "C:\Users\bajan\Desktop\Informatica\Python\YoutubeSearchBot\lib\site-packages\googleapiclient\http.py", line 191, in _retry_request
    resp, content = http.request(uri, method, *args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\bajan\Desktop\Informatica\Python\YoutubeSearchBot\lib\site-packages\httplib2\__init__.py", line 1701, in request
    (response, content) = self._request(
  File "C:\Users\bajan\Desktop\Informatica\Python\YoutubeSearchBot\lib\site-packages\httplib2\__init__.py", line 1421, in _request
    (response, content) = self._conn_request(conn, request_uri, method, body, headers)
  File "C:\Users\bajan\Desktop\Informatica\Python\YoutubeSearchBot\lib\site-packages\httplib2\__init__.py", line 1343, in _conn_request
    conn.connect()
  File "C:\Users\bajan\Desktop\Informatica\Python\YoutubeSearchBot\lib\site-packages\httplib2\__init__.py", line 1133, in connect
    sock.connect((self.host, self.port))
```

Libraries i use:

```
from sendgrid.helpers.mail import Mail, Email, To, Content
from sendgrid import SendGridAPIClient
from datetime import datetime, timedelta
from googleapiclient.discovery import build
from tkinter.filedialog import askopenfile
import tkinter
import customtkinter
import pandas as pd
import sendgrid
import os
import re
```

So i thinks it's something about the port or it might be from youtube server? I have tried everything i could find on the internet but i failed. Please help. Thanks!

Comment: From your traceback, looks like the error is coming from code called inside a library called YoutubeSearchBot - are you able to share the erroring code, or at least details on the library your using?

Comment: I changed the code. I couldn't post so much because it has 170 lines of code. I hope you understand